# Is it possible to implement a vectorized version of a Maxout activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, numpy, activation-function

I want to implement an efficient and vectorized Maxout activation function using python numpy.
Here is the paper in which "[Maxout Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4389v4.pdf)" was introduced (by Goodfellow et al).

For example, if k = 2:

```
def maxout(x, W1, b1, W2, b2):
    return np.maximum(np.dot(W1.T,x) + b1, np.dot(W2.T, x) + b2)
```

Where x is a N*D matrix.

Suppose k is an arbitrary value(say 5). Is it possible to avoid for loops when calculating each `wx + b`? I couldn't come up with any vectorized solutions.

Comment: Check out [np.tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you could combine all the weight vectors into a matrix W and all b's into a vector b, then you could do

```
np.maximum(np.dot(W.T,x)  + b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to this field, but isn't the result of "np.dot(W.T, x) + b" a single matrix itself? np.maximum can't work with one argument.

Comment: W is an k x n matrix. X and b are n-dim vectors. The result of the operation is a k-dim vector - of which you determine the max.

Comment: Ah. I forgot to mention that in my case, X is an N  * D matrix.

Comment: What are the dimensions of W?

Comment: If x is a d-dim vector, then W must be a d * m * k matrix and b must be a m * k matrix. (Where m is the number of hidden units, d size of input vector(x), and k number of linear models). But what if x is a n*d matrix instead of a vector?